# Generics and Parent/Child architecture

Tags: c#, generics, parent-child

I'm building an architecture with **inheritable** generics and parent-children relations.
I have one major problem: I can't make both the child and the parent aware of each other's type, only one of the two.

I need both the child and the parent to be aware of each other's type.

**Scenario 1**: Parent knows child type, but child only knows generic parent with generic children.

```
public class Child
{
    public Parent<Child> Parent;
}

public class Parent<TChild>
    where TChild : Child
{
    public List<TChild> Children;
}
```

**Scenario 2**: Child knows parent type, but parent only knows generic children with generic parent.

```
public class Child<TParent>
    where TParent : Parent
{
    public TParent Parent;
}

public class Parent
{
    public List<Child<Parent>> Children;
}
```

**Scenario 3**: The utopic but unachievable scenario:

```
public class Child<TParent>
    where TParent : Parent
{
    public TParent Parent;
}

public class Parent<TChild>
    where TChild : Child
{
    public List<TChild> Children;
}
```

Of course, scenario 3 won't compile, because Parent and Child take a second generic type that would be *their own* type, but I can't (or at least don't know how!) to specify it is their own type.

I'm falling in some kind of a infinite loop/recursion/ball-throw here, please help me before I drown.

Good luck.

**EDIT**: If I wasn't clear, I can reference my types yes, but if the user derives Child into FooChild, and accesses the children of the parent of FooChild, these will only be Child, and not FooChild, as it should be.

**Failure Example with Scenario 1**:

```
public class Child
{
    public Parent<Child> Parent;
}

public class Parent<TChild>
    where TChild : Child, new()
{
    public List<TChild> Children;
}

public class FooChild : Child
{
    public int Required;

    public void Bar()
    {
        foreach (Child child in this.Parent.Children)
        {
            int x = child.Required; // cannot be accessed!
        }
    }
}
```

**Failure Example with Scenario 2**:

```
public class Child<TParent>
    where TParent : Parent
{
    public TParent Parent;
}

public class Parent
{
    public List<Child<Parent>> Children;
}

public class FooChild : Child<Parent>
{
    public int Required;

    public void Bar()
    {
        foreach (Child<Parent> child in this.Parent.Children)
        {
            int x = child.Required; // cannot be accessed!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely in the first two scenarios the type of the "unknown" one is implicit. i.e. scenario 2 (seems the most logical to me) surely the parent can derive the child type as being the same type as itself?

Comment: It's not possible to do this in C#. You are creating mutually recursive type definitions and C# is guaranteed to poo its pants at that.

Comment: @OJ: If it shall not be done, than thou must... hack it.

Comment: When building an architecture I'm not a fan of hacking it :)

Comment: @OJ: Me neither, but what else could I do; cry in Redmond?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You certainly can do what you ask. Define your classes like this:

```
public abstract class Child<P, C>
    where P : Parent<P, C>
    where C : Child<P, C>
{
    public P Parent { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Parent<P, C>
    where P : Parent<P, C>
    where C : Child<P, C>
{
    public List<C> Children = new List<C>();
}
```

Then you can define your concrete class like this:

```
public class Cat : Parent<Cat, Kitten>
{
}

public class Kitten : Child<Cat, Kitten>
{
}

public class Dog : Parent<Dog, Puppy>
{
}

public class Puppy : Child<Dog, Puppy>
{
}
```

Now you have your fully-typed parent-child relationships. This code now works:

```
var fluffy = new Cat();
var fluffette1 = new Kitten() { Parent = fluffy };
var fluffette2 = new Kitten() { Parent = fluffy };

fluffy.Children.Add(fluffette1);
fluffy.Children.Add(fluffette2);

var butch = new Dog();
var butchette1 = new Puppy() { Parent = butch };
var butchette2 = new Puppy() { Parent = butch };

butch.Children.Add(butchette1);
butch.Children.Add(butchette2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer rests on the fact that both Parent and Child must be abstract and therefore defined by the implementer. However, this is perfect, as it is exactly the only case in which such a scenario would be useful. Wow, I'm still in awe for your answer. Would give 10+ if I could. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Uh-oh, one major flaw: "new()" constraint is not available with that pattern. Meaning the Parent can't, for instance, create the Child.

Comment: Mm, I went around it with Activator.CreateInstance(). Strange it's just so... easy.

Comment: @Lazlo: You can also work around it by passing a child factory delegate to your parent, which is the only option if your child has a parameterized constructor.  If your child factory requires a reference to the parent (likely), then you'll have to do some casting:  `protected ParentBase(Func<P, C> createChild){child = createChild((P)this);}`

Comment: @Lazlo - `Parent` & `Child` don't have to be `abstract`. I just do it that way because I intend the classes to be inherited. Also you can add the `new()` constraint without a problem - just constrain like this: `where C : Child<P, C>, new()` - on both base classes. Worked fine for me, but you do need to do the following cast to set the parent: `c.Parent = (P)(object)this;`;

Comment: I actually used Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TChild), constructors), which is even more convenient than the previous model with "new()" especially since there is no performance overhead http://mironabramson.com/blog/post/2008/08/Fast-version-of-the-ActivatorCreateInstance-method-using-IL.aspx (see comments!)

Comment: @Lazlo - Using the `Activator` is fine, but it doesn't ensure that your child classes can be constructed by the parent as the child could have a constructor with arbitrary parameters. That's why the `new()` constraint is there. However, good unit testing would overcome that issue. Glad to hear that it is working for you.