# Manipulator Factory

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, generics, inheritance

**EDIT4 Gave Truck a property to show the SetNrOfWheels method is tailored to a specific Truck**

**EDIT3 Made a connection between B - Vehicle and C1 - Truck**

**EDIT2 Removed interface on B**

**EDIT1 Changed Car into Vehicle**

I have two questions about a problem I ran into several times. I wonder if I must use another pattern, or if someone could point me in the right/better direction.

If you know an article here describing the answer, please let me know and I will try to delete this one.

Consider an abstract base class B (i.e. Vehicle), which is inherited by a number of child classes, C1, C2, etc. (i.e. Truck, Motor) Suppose these classes are pure data carriers, i.e. data contracts, and consist of a number of properties. Although not strictly necessary for the story, they use a default constructor without arguments and all properties are public, and simple value type objects. They may or may not inherit some predefined properties, but most importantly, B is more or less a marker, rather than it enforces functionality (since it is a data contract).

Example:

```
abstract Vehicle {
  int NrOfWheels { get; set;}
}

Truck : Vehicle {
  bool HasExtraTrailer { get; set; }
}
```

Now consider a manipulator of B called BM (i.e. VehicleWheelSetter), which is either an abstract base class or an interface (you decide what's best here ;)). It has (at least abstract) functionality to manipulate B classes. Suppose each manipulator, i.e. C1M, C2M, (TruckWheelSetter, MotorWheelSetter) inherits from BM. Important is, that the type is enforced, ergo, C1M only manipulates C1 type of classes. This could be enforced by BM being generic, say BM<T> where T : B, although this is limited (this would allow for an XM : BM<B> still)

Example:

```
interface IVehicleWheelSetter<in T> where T : Vehicle {
  void SetNrOfWheels(T vehicle)
}

TruckWheelSetter : IVehicleWheelSetter<Truck> {
  void SetNrOfWheels(Truck vehicle) { 
    vehicle.NrOfWheels = 2 * 3;
    if (vehicle.HasExtraTrailer) vehicle.NrOfWheels += 2 * 2;
} } }
```

**Question 1: Is there a way to make sure a concrete BM (i.e. C1M) is always manipulating a concrete B (in this case C1)? Or does this require another pattern?**

Let's assume that in general, this will be much more complex then assigning a number (which could obviously be retrieved from a configuration or database). It's not a coincidence I wrote 2 * 3, to show that this could be a complex operation.

Suppose I know I get B classes all the time in some service that has to do a manipulation, like a factory, something like this:

```
VehicleWheelSetterFactory {
  IVehicleWheelSetter<T> CreateVehicleWheelSetter<T>() where T : Vehicle {
    // code to create the right selector here
} }
```

Now, there are various ways to do this:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(Truck)) 
  return (IVehicleWheelSetter<T>)(new TruckWheelSetter());
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

or some more advanced reflection based options.

There are some problems with this, aside from some 'it does not feel right'. There will also be cases in which a generic does not work, i.e. T is unknown. In that case, a Type in the argument could help:

```
object CreateVehicleWheelSetter(Type vehicleType) { 
  if (vehicleType == typeof(Truck)) 
    return new TruckWheelSetter();
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

but how to cast the object to an IVehicleWheelSetter<T>? T is still unknown! So, maybe the interface should be this:

```
interface ICarWheelSetter
{
    void SetNrOfWheels(Vehicle vehicle);
}
```

But now I have the original problem: I cannot guarantee the Vehicle is a Truck in TruckWheelSetter. This also not be resolved this way:

```
interface IVehicleWheelSetter
{
    void SetNrOfWheels<T>(T car) where T : Vehicle;
}
```

**Question 2: Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: Have a look at this answer and see if it helps in this case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5386425/259769

Comment: "If you know an article here describing the answer, please let me know and I will try to delete this one." please don't do that. If the question is a duplicate, it will be flagged as such and linked with the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your problem (how can T be unknown, if you parse concrete instances), but anyway, wouldn't this be easy:

```
public class CarWheelSetter
{
    public static void SetNrOfWheels<T>(T car) where T : Car
    {
        WheelSetterFor<T>().SetNrOfWheels(car);
    }

    private static ICarWheelSetter<T> WheelSetterFor<T>() where T : Car
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Truck))
        {
            return new TruckWheelSetter() as ICarWheelSetter<T>;
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed Car to Vehicle. If you get an object, of which you do not know yet what it is (i.e. you get a Vehicle from a collection of random Vehicles) you can ask something like 'randomVehicle.GetType()', but you cannot easily call the generic method I believe, right?

Comment: In general: your Vehicle-from-a-collection-of-random-Vehicles is an instance of a specific class, be it a Truck or a Car. So, if you call a method DoSomeFor<T>(T vehicle) you actually call either DoSomeFor<Truck>(Truck vehicle) or DoSomeFor<Car>(Car vehicle).

Answer (score 0):

> Consider an abstract base class/interface B

These are not arbitrarily interchangeable things. I would expect a `public class abstract Car` not an interface. The purpose of `interface` - the C# keyword specific meaning - is to define "the same, but different" behavior for unrelated classes. For example we might want a `IFly` interface so we can "fly" bugs, birds, and bombers - that are otherwise unrelated classes.

But `Car` and `Truck` are related so through the basic mechanisms of inheritance and polymorphism there is no need for arbitrary interfaces in handling `Car` sub-classes.

> Suppose these classes are pure data carriers

The fundamental OO idea of a class is *data + its methods*. The idea of `Car` and its derivatives needs to be fleshed out. This will inform the car factory design.

And I'd expect many `Car` properties are their own classes. If a wheel assembly is as complex as suggested then maybe that should be a class.

> B is more or less a marker

A `Car` is just a marker - nothing essentially? How can you build nothing? By building anything, which is where this design is going I think. No wonder you're trying to build Granular interfaces like `ICarWheelSetter`. But these are just wrong here. Imagine what the code would look like when you did this for every property in `Car` and its derivatives. It seems me that this is a symptom of an inadequately defined domain model. As shown, I have no idea what a `Car` is and its derivatives more so.  Because we have nothing concrete to work any sub-class might be anything and the code seems to support this fuzzy idea.

> Is there a way to make sure a concrete BM (i.e. C1M) is always manipulating a concrete B (in this case C1)? Or does this require another pattern?

I'm reminded of the [visitor design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html). I imagine a `Garage` fixing a `Car`. The `Garage` knows how to manipulate a `Car` to fix it. Further, a derived `BMWGarage` will know how to fix a BMW `Car` sub-class.

And so I imagine a `Garage` inheritance hierarchy that mirrors the `Car` hierarchy. Maybe not precisely: a `ForeignCarGarage` might handle several different `Car` types.

> Is there a way to make sure a concrete BM is always manipulating a concrete B?

Of course. Call the factory and tell it to make a car, and then a garage for that car

```
var myBeamer = CarFactory.Create(carEnum.BMW); 
var beamerGarage = GarageFactory.Create (typeof(myBeamer).FullName);
```

The above suggests a need for an [abstract factory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbjAsdAK4xQ). Note there are 3 "levels" of factory. Which to use is a matter of the complexity of what needs building. Further, we might see a [builder pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html) to coordinate the complex steps in car (or garage) creation.

So that might mean we create a factory for the specific `Car` derivative and its garage. This BMWFactory uses BMW parts - classes like `BMWWheelAssembly`.

```
var BMWFactory = new CarFactory(carEnum.Bmw);
var myBeamer = BMWFactory.Create();
```

AND NOW a `CarFactory` might implement an `interface`, or be an `abstract` class - but not both I think. If there is base-implementation I'd expect an `abstract` class. The `abstract` class could [template](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html) the assembly process so assembly - calling methods - is done in the right order.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tend to agree on the base class thing for the data contract, however, in general you seem to try to refute the assumptions. The assumptions are not easily changed, in my case, but actually I suspect more people have run into this. I would love to write functionality on the data contract, but in most cases, you cannot do this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tend to agree on the base class thing for the data contract, however, in general you seem to try to refute the assumptions. Try to stick to the assumptions as they are not easily changed. I would love to write functionality on the data contract, but in most cases, you cannot do this. Think of WCF contracts or data base entities. There are also other reasons to keep data and functionality separated (functionality is too heavy, proprietary, etc). Now, you could argue you need to wrap Truck, and give it functionality, but then you end up with my problem.