# WPF - TreeView adding Children to Children completly dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, treeview

I have build a completly working logic in WinForms to insert Data in a TreeView that comes from a DB, so I cant just put a datatable behind the treeview and be happy, because I need to build nodes and undernodes and undernodes, etc.
The working Code in old WinForms:

```
    private void waregroup()
    {
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
        string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM APWGRUPP ORDER BY WG_WGSCHL ASC";
        string str_key = "";
        string str_desc = "";
        int int_node0 = 0;
        int int_node1= 0;
        int int_node2 = 0;
        int int_node3 = 0;
        int int_node4 = 0;

        myDataSet = ImportDBF(sqlStatement);
        myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables["Table"];
        foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
        {
            str_desc = row.Field<string>(1);
            str_key = row.Field<string>(2);
            switch (str_key.Length)
            {
                case 1:
                    trv_waregroup.Nodes.Add(str_key + "-" + str_desc);
                    int_node0++;
                    int_node1 = 0;
                    int_node2 = 0;
                    int_node3 = 0;
                    int_node4 = 0;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    trv_waregroup.Nodes[int_node0 - 1].Nodes.Add(str_key + "-" + str_desc);
                    int_node1++;
                    int_node2 = 0;
                    int_node3 = 0;
                    int_node4 = 0;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    trv_waregroup.Nodes[int_node0 - 1].Nodes[int_node1 - 1].Nodes.Add(str_key + "-" + str_desc);
                    int_node2++;
                    int_node3 = 0;
                    int_node4 = 0;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    trv_waregroup.Nodes[int_node0 - 1].Nodes[int_node1 - 1].Nodes[int_node2 - 1].Nodes.Add(str_key + "-" + str_desc);
                    int_node3++;
                    int_node4 = 0;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    trv_waregroup.Nodes[int_node0 - 1].Nodes[int_node1 - 1].Nodes[int_node2 - 1].Nodes[int_node3 - 1].Nodes.Add(str_key + "-" + str_desc);
                    int_node4++;
                    break;
                default:
                    trv_waregroup.Nodes[int_node0 - 1].Nodes[int_node1 - 1].Nodes[int_node2 - 1].Nodes[int_node3 - 1].Nodes[int_node4 - 1].Nodes.Add(str_key + "-" + str_desc);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I cant use the logic with Items[Counter].Add anymore, but the only possible solution I can think of is using the enumeration. But all I found was using the Header as new Item to add the new node to.

I tried this way, but dont get a usable Item to work with:

```
TreeViewItem temp = (TreeViewItem)_WareGroups.Items.GetItemAt(Node0 - 1);
_WareGroups.Items.Add(GroupKey + "-" + GroupDesc);
```

Anyone got an idea how I can add my nearly 2500 Items this way?

Comment: if this is WPF, please delete all that horrible code immediately and start reading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode).

Comment: Basically, you don't "add nodes to a TreeView" or "create TreeViewItems" or anything like that in procedural code in WPF. Instead, you will create a proper [Hierarchical Data Structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5386239/generics-and-parent-child-architecture) suitable to be used by a [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx). BTW, It's also strongly recommended that you have at least a minimum respect for layering and move DB-related code off the UI layer.

Comment: And please, use correct casing on method names. It should be `WareGroup()`, if anything.

Comment: no, it was WinForms and I worked with my old VisualBasic Knowledge. I am treansferring it to WPF and I am using correct camelCase and PascalCase in my newly created Code. But MVVM is a book with 7 seals to me, i.e. I dont have any plan on how to use DataBindings, a.s.o.  But I'm trying to learn it. Your links can be helpful, but they need time to learn I presume I dont have. But thats the way live goes, hm? :)

Comment: You can A) spend some time learning how to use WPF properly, or you can B) spend twice as much time trying to force an archaic inadequate procedural approach into a properly designed framework that's not intended to be used that way. Either way you're going to spend time, but option A seems to allow you to actually learn stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. If someone is interested:

XAML:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Height="{Binding ElementName=AdminConsoleWindow, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=(@VALUE/3)}">
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public partial class AdminConsole : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items { get; set; }

    public AdminConsole()
    {
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddWareGroups()
    {
        DataTable MyTable = DBase.GetWareGroups();
        foreach (DataRow MyRow in MyTable.Rows)
        {
            string ItemDescription = MyRow.Field<string>(1);
            string ItemKey = MyRow.Field<string>(2);
            MyItem NewItem = new MyItem();
            NewItem.Header = ItemKey + " - " + ItemDescription;
            if (ItemKey.Length == 1)
            {
                this.Items.Add(NewItem);
            }
            else if (ItemKey.Length == 2 || ItemKey.Length == 5 || ItemKey.Length == 6)
            {
                IterateSubItems(1, NewItem, ItemKey, this.Items);
            }
            else // if (ItemKey.Length == 4 || ItemKey.Length == 8)
            {
                IterateSubItems(2, NewItem, ItemKey, this.Items);
            }
        }
    }

    private void IterateSubItems(int shortenLength, MyItem newItem, string itemKey, ObservableCollection<MyItem> myCollection)
    {
        foreach (MyItem ItemChild in myCollection)
        {
            if (ItemChild.Header.Substring(0, ItemChild.Header.IndexOf(" - ")).Equals(itemKey.Substring(0, itemKey.Length - shortenLength)))
            {
                ItemChild.SubItems.Add(newItem);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (ItemChild.SubItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    IterateSubItems(shortenLength, newItem, itemKey, ItemChild.SubItems);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And in an extra Class:

```
public class MyItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var evt = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (evt != null)
            evt(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    private string _Header = "Item";
    public string Header
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Header;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._Header != value)
            {
                this._Header = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Header");
            }
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _SubItems = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> SubItems
    {
        get
        {
            return this._SubItems;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._SubItems != value)
            {
                this._SubItems = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SubItems");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like that :

```
foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
{
  str_desc = row.Field<string>(1);
  str_key = row.Field<string>(2);

  TreeNode node = new TreeNode(str_key + "-" + str_desc);

  int lvl = 1;

  addToLvl(lvl, trv_waregroup, trv_waregroup.Nodes[trv_waregroup.GetNodeCount(false) - 1], str_key.Length, node);

}

public void addToLvl(int actualLvl, TreeView tv, TreeNode last, int lvlToReach, TreeNode nodeToAdd)
{
  if (actualLvl == lvlToReach)
    last.Add(node); //wpf ?? last.Nodes.Add(node);
  else
    addToLvl(actualLvl++, tv, last.LastNode, lvlToreach, nodeToAdd);
}
```

Comment: last.Nodes does no longer exist in WPF, its now items.add, but there are no longer Nodes[2].Nodes[5].Nodes.Add. That is my problem.

Comment: I would like to say yes, but you use something like trv_waregroup.Nodes[trv_waregroup.GetNodeCount(false) - 1] and that does not work any longer. You cannot address the nodes per index anymore.